# Expansion of a similar question

Tags: geometry

I was observing this question: [Concyclic points on a regular polygon](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006494/concyclic-points-on-a-regular-polygon)

and I have a problem that came up into my head.

If we know that a set of two concyclic points are the vertices of a regular n-gon, and another set of two concyclic points are the vertices of regular n-gon, and these sets "overlap" (meaning that if the sets were {A,B} and {C,D}, then the order of the points on the circle would be A, C, B, D) can we prove that the set of four points is on the same regular n-gon?

Comment: For a regular n-gon, its vertices are all con-cyclic. Therefore, A, B, C, D are con-cyclic.